# ¿Tiene un Bug la versión GooglePlayServices para unity?

Tags: unity3d, google-play, google-play-games

Al añadir el paquete a Unity, este en concreto:

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/current-build

Al ir a compilar el .apk sale este error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.firebase:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4 -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\pc\Documents\Unity\Battle Run\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.4.0\res"

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:12: Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '$'.
]

stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package:C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar
```

No consigo saber de dónde viene ese `'$'`.

El manifest es el siguiente:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application>

 <!-- Required for Nearby Connections API -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.SERVICE_ID"
        android:value="" />

    <!-- the space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="\ " />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
        android:value="\ 0.9.34" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
```

Comment: agrega tu archivo build.gradle!

Comment: Estoy en Unity3D no encuentro el build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Victor, revisa tu `AndroidManifest.xml` el error indica :

> AndroidManifest.xml:12: Tag  attribute authorities has
>   invalid character '$'.

Si es que lo tenias anteriormente, solo sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos gradle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya eso ya lo se, pero no estoy con Android Studio estoy con Unity. A parte mi Manifest está arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual se explica en el [ReadME.md del plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md), siguiendo estos pasos debería funcionar:

1. Habilitar tu juego [en Google Play Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling)

2. Configurar al menos un recurso:
   [image: recurso en Play Games]

3. Copiar los recursos
   [image: XML de los recursos]

4. En [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d), ir a <kbd>Window</kbd>↣<kbd>Google Play Games</kbd>↣<kbd>Setup...</kbd>↣<kbd>Android Setup</kbd>
   y pegar los recursos que recién copiaste
   [image: Configuración del plugin]